# Log process or program network usage under windows

Tags: windows, logging, network-monitoring

I need a wireshark like - maybe firewall - application for Windows 7 which can log all the http network access a program and/or process does and doesn't eat up a helluva lot of resources. It has to run for weeks/months, so if it does this in the background that definetly helps. Does any kind of program like this exists for Windows? IPTABLES? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)

Comment: TADAAA! That's what I wanted. Thank you a thousand times!!!